# list view item click not getting called in android

Tags: android, events, android-listview, onclick, click

I'm showing a list. In onCreate I have code

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

            Log.v("list clicked", "list item no: " + position);
            Toast.makeText(DisplayImagesActivity.this, "Btn delete position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent intentImageDetails = new Intent(DisplayImagesActivity.this, ImageDetailActivity.class);

            intentImageDetails.putExtra("image", imageBitmap);
            intentImageDetails.putExtra("name", listImageInfo.get(position).getImage_name());
            intentImageDetails.putExtra("amount", listImageInfo.get(position).getAmount());
            intentImageDetails.putExtra("desc", listImageInfo.get(position).getImage_description());
            intentImageDetails.putExtra("id", listImageInfo.get(position).getImage_id());
            intentImageDetails.putExtra("date", listImageInfo.get(position).getDate_created());

            startActivity(intentImageDetails);
        }
    });
```

and adapter code is

```
public class MyImageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public MyImageListAdapter() {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) DisplayImagesActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listImageInfo.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listImageInfo.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        }

        TextView tvName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        TextView tvTime = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
        final Button btnDelete = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);

        image.setImageDrawable(listImageInfo.get(position).getImage());

        tvName.setText("Name: " + listImageInfo.get(position).getImage_name());
        tvTime.setText("Date: " + listImageInfo.get(position).getDate_created());

        // btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        // @Override
        // public void onClick(View v) {
        // final int position = listView.getPositionForView((View)
        // v.getParent());
        // Log.v("delete btn clicked", "delete btn no: " + position);
        // Toast.makeText(DisplayImagesActivity.this,
        // "Btn delete position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // }
        // });

        // listImageInfo.get(position).getImage().getClass();
        // image.setImageBitmap(bm)
        return vi;
    }
}
```

But not getting called list view click code, what wrong i'm doing?

Comment: Remove the Button in your adapter and retry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in xml file set `btn_delete` focus false, i think button is focused when you click on List so you have to set

`android:focusable="false"` in xml

or

`btnDelete.setFocusable(false);`

Comment: [see this turs](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html)